# py2neo command in neo4j BOLT driver

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have a command written in python using the py2neo to access the name of an exchange. This works.

```
graph = Graph()
stmt = 'MATCH (i:Index{uniqueID: 'SPY'})-[r:belongsTo]->(e:Exchange) RETURN e.name'
exchName = graph.cypher.execute(stmt)[0][0]
```

Can this be converted to a BOLT neo4j-driver statement? I always get an error. I want to avoid an iterator statement where I loop through the StatementResult.

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo4j"))
session = driver.session()
stmt = 'MATCH (i:Index{uniqueID: 'SPY'})-[r:belongsTo]->(e:Exchange) RETURN e.name'
exchName = session.run(stmt)[0][0]
TypeError: 'StatementResult' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store the results of `session.run()` in a `list` to retain them:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo4j"))
session = driver.session()
stmt = 'MATCH (i:Index{uniqueID: 'SPY'})-[r:belongsTo]->(e:Exchange) RETURN e.name'

# transform to list to retain result
exchName = list(session.run(stmt))[0][0]
```

See the docs: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#result-retain